# No internet when a specific lan cable is connected

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, modem

Having a very strange issue - we recently had someone move into our spare bedroom about a month ago, and since he's arrived, our internet has died about 4 times where no one could connect to the internet (I can't even log into the router). He connects directly to the router via ethernet cable. I never noticed that this particular connection was the issue, however, until tonight.

I came home this evening, and we had no internet. Contacted the ISP, they said they're not seeing any issue from their end. Tried to log in to the router, and I could not connect. Ran IPCONFIG in cmd and I was getting no results for the ethernet cable I have plugged in. No default gateway, nothing. Tried to connect to the ISP's modem, and again no results.

Rebooted the modem and the router at least 5 times each, keeping them both off for multiple minutes before turning them back on, and still nothing. So I decided to plug out all the ethernet cables connected to the ASUS router, and connect them directly to the ISP's modem because something seemed very strange. Suddenly, my phone connected to the network! I thought maybe the ISP had fixed something, so I plugged back in the ethernet cables to the ASUS router. Net gone again.

One by one, I plugged out the ethernet cables trying to see if it was one of the connections. And of course, disconnecting the spare bedroom's ethernet cable brought the internet back to life... But now, the person who exists in that bedroom has no internet. A

ny thoughts on what the issue could be so I can resolve this? He has a laptop with Windows 10, an ethernet cable and he uses an ethernet splitter on his laptop so he can extend the connection to another device (usually an IP Phone, or another computer). Do you think this could be causing the issue?

He doesn't have internet when this issue occurs, so I know he's not intentionally blocking the internet.

Comment: Have him try a different cable.  If it works, then the original cable is causing the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in order for a splitter to work properly, you need to have a splitter at your source and one at your destination. Tell him to not use the splitter and plug one Ethernet cord into the computer and see if the issue persists. If the issue does not occur, get him a switch for his room and use that instead of the splitter.

Comment: Is it a passive splitter or a powered 'Ethernet switch'?

Comment: @keltari I will give this a try - Unfortunately, it doesn't always happen so hopefully I can try it when it does happen

Comment: @DrZoo I did not realize this. I've asked him to not use it for now.

Comment: @user1686 I believe it's a passive splitter